# Bootstrap carousel with background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

My client has bootstrap template. I made a slider there:
[Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRE6z.png)

Images are mooving only in laptop. I want to add description to the right side of the laptop (Now sliding description does not work). And have no idea how to do it. Tried many variations. 
Or better and faster just to write slider myself, not using Bootstrap?

Will be greatful for any help!

html:

```
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/people.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/people.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/people.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-description current">
    <div>Отчёт по результатам обследования в форме документа в PS QUASTIO PRO</div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-description">
    <div>Отчёт по результатам обследования в форме документа</div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-description">
    <div>Отчёт по результатам обследования</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myCarousel{
    height: 510px;
    background: url(../images/computer.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 1350px auto;

}

#myCarousel .carousel-inner{
    width: 441px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 225px;
    top: 24px;
}

.carousel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item img{
    width: 441px;
    height: 250px;
}

.carousel-description{
    display: none;
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 150px;
    top: 185px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.carousel-description.current{
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code which doesnt use any library and is similar to the pic you attached ,just change the pics path from css.
you can control the speed of slides from changing variable yourinterval

```
var yourinterval=2000;
```

DEMO:http://jsbin.com/xegufazuyi/2/edit?html,css,js,output